# How big is the city in the film Dark City?

Tags: dark-city

In the 1998 film *[Dark City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_City_(1998_film))*, how big was the city supposed to be? What's its approximate size?

Comment: It looks to be about the size of a city. Maybe 10 miles diameter?

Answer (score 2):

Based solely on the shots near the end of the film where we see the city starting to turn over, allowing the "sun" to rise for the first time since it was populated with abducted humans, it appears to be similar in size to the downtown core of a middle sized city -- perhaps a little larger than downtown Seattle ca. 2000 (total population half a million, but only a few thousand actually lived downtown at that time), certainly larger than Portland, Oregon of the same era: perhaps five miles diameter (surely not much larger).

With most of the population seemingly living in apartments above businesses, buildings ranging from 2-3 floors to twenty or so, that would be big enough to support a population of (at a guess) from fifty thousand to a hundred thousand.